# Grails upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4: No Datastore Session bound to thread

Tags: grails

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Grails 2.3.7 to 2.4.3 but many pages give the error:

> No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow
>   creation of non-transactional one here

The only config I've changed is the plugins portion of BuildConfig.groovy.  Am I missing something?

I'm using the Hibernate 3.6.10.16 plugin with Oracle 11.

Update: It seems related to running a query from a gsp.  Here's a mock example that works in 2.3.7.

```
<g:set var="allBooks" value="${Books.createCriteria().listDistinct { }}" />
```

> Error evaluating expression [Books.createCriteria().listDistinct { }] on
>   line [1]: No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does
>   not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: Have you tried the hibernate4 plugin? There are a lot of update notes for Grails 2.4.3 possibly related with your problem (like: "It is recommended to set Hibernate OSIVI flush mode to "manual" for applications that haven't been upgraded from Hibernate 3 plugin" etc.). Anyway I would recommend to move the queries from the view into a service. The controller calls the service, and populates the model which gets passed into the view.

Comment: I've tried hibernate4 but we use Oracle Label Security and our solution is hibernate3 dependent, so that's a whole other issue.
Our design is template driven and each template (view) fetches all the data it needs.  This gives us flexability to plop a template anywhere we want.  Correctness aside, it would take some effort to convert all the templates into services, though our services are working fine...  I was hoping for a quick fix to get the old behavior back. :)
Looks like my choice is to move all view queries into controllers/services, or to get hibernate4 working with OLS.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's difficult to know exactly from the info you gave, but I have 3 options for you as I've seen this error several times when upgrading either Grail's version or plugins:
1.- Check if there is a newer version for the plugins you are using, specially hibernate, this fixes a lot of bugs with every update.
2.- Check your database connector, try a different one since you changes grail's version it may have incompatibilities with the one you were using.
3.- Try changing the JDK version you are using. I've seen a lot this problem when changing Grails version and changing JDK from 6 to 7 and viceversa.

I hope although I couldn't give you the exact answer, I gave you a light towards where to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I updated everything under Grails 2.3 to the latest available to make the jump to 2.4 as small as possible.  Hibernate (3.6.10.16), Java (JDK 1.7.0_76), ojdbc6 (11.2.0.3) etc.  I was hoping to simply update some "configuration" as the error says, to get the old behavior.  I've also tried Java 8 and hibernate4 but that's a whole other issue.